# Using javascript in HTML to insert data into preexisting excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am creating an automated production schedule for my work. 
Our software can export data from each individual job with an HTML template.
We have a standing excel spreadsheet with our production schedule. I was wanting to see if there is a way that I can use some javascript in the HTML template that our software runs to send the job data to the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: If the data on the page is in tables (or otherwise predictably-organized) you could open the page directly in excel and use VBA in your standing workbook to pick out the data.  Difficult to make suggestion without more to go on.

Comment: I am trying to automate the entire process. The software directly provides the data in the HTML file and I need a way to automatically load that data into the spreadsheet.

Comment: You can't have webpage open up Excel on a local PC without some pretty terrible security settings.  Also, you'd still need to visit the page on a PC with access to the Excel file (which would need to be closed at the time)

Comment: @tim williams It is not a webpage. Our software just outputs data into an HTML document. Like when I am creating the HTML template it uses I write to output (example below)

Comment: How do you envision this would happen automatically? - you have to run the report and then presumably you have an HTML file on disk.  You will need to run *something* on that file to transfer the information to your excel file.  It could be written in any language you're comfortable with.

Comment: the report is an HTML file. So I thought that there was a way that I could embed some code in it so that when our software runs the HTML report it would update our excel file.

Comment: Where would that code run? - does your reporting tool save the output to file, or open it in a browser?  If it were opened in IE then potentially you could add script to the output which would then run to update your excel file.  See for example: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234774/how-to-automate-excel-from-an-html-web-page-by-using-jscript

Comment: So the software takes a HTML Report template and inserts all the data that I request and then opens it in a browser and  then saves it in another folder of all past reports.

Comment: In that case you could take a look at that link I just posted and try that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a xml file with javascript from the HTML template (you can use this method: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12504/Writing-XML-using-JavaScript ). Then import the xml data to the Excel spreadsheet using this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9lFB8-PjIg .

Comment: do you know if there is a way to automate the conversion of xml to xls and put it into my production schedule?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML template uses certain keywords that our software replaces

```
<TABLE>
  <TR><TD>Customer Name:</TD><TD>[OMAX_AskFor_Customer Name]</TD></TR>
  <TR><TD>File Name:</TD><TD>[OMAX_FileName]</TD></TR>
  <!-- and so on with other data values-->
</TABLE>
```

When I run the report on our software it replaces the [OMAX_] with whatever data it is requesting from the job. I want to extract the data in the HTML file to add it to our production schedule